# Apply a constraint if condition with OR-Tools CP Solver

Tags: or-tools

I'm implementing a similar solution for the Job-Shop problem with one difference: I don't know the machine that has to perform each task. Solving that is a part of the problem too. We can say, in fact, that I'm trying to solve a combination of the Nurse Problem and the Job-Shop Problem.

More concretely, I have some tasks T with duration D that have to be performed by some specific employees E due to their nature N (let's say fron-end tasks, back-end, and so on) in a specific order O.

I have:

- An array of T int vars that can acquire a value in the range of E (employee that's going to perform a task).
- An array of fixed duration interval vars (to scheduling them knowing it's duration D).
- E sequence vars which should be the sequence of tasks (interval vars) that an employee is going to perform.
- Some constraints for the relation N between tasks and employees.
- Some other constraints for the order O.

A way to solve this is: first solve the assignment problem, then schedule the tasks. I have achieved this.

However I want to implement it as an unique solution.

I am stuck at this: How to create a disjunctive constraint that depends on the int vars I created before?

To those who need to see code:

```
for i in range(number_employees):
    disj = solver.DisjunctiveConstraint([interval_var[task_id] if int_var[task_id] == i] ,'i_name')
   [...]
```

Of course, that doesn't work.

I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Did you try to use `AddAllDiferents(intvars)` methods ?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/cpp/flexible_jobshop.cc#L67 i.e. you can create several set reusing the same tasks to have different set of disjunctiveConstraint...

Answer (score 4):

Should should have a look at the CP-SAT solver.
It supports half-reified constraints.

That is,  (in python):

> model.AddNoOverlap([list of intervals]).OnlyEnforceIf(boolvar)
>
> model.Add(x == i).OnlyEnforceIf(boolvar)
>
> model.Add(x != i).OnlyEnforceIf(boolvar.Not())

See: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

[Laurent Perron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9971759/laurent-perron), I modified [no_overlap_sample_sat.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/554cbccaa95b4c11eced13f145de1bf468e1f919/ortools/sat/samples/no_overlap_sample_sat.py#L50) to follow your suggestion but it doesn't work. What I modified is:

```
# No Overlap constraint.
boolvar = model.NewBoolVar('boolvar')
i = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'i')
x = model.NewIntVar(0, 10, 'x')
model.Add(i - x == 0)
model.AddNoOverlap(
    [task_0, task_1, task_2, weekend_0, weekend_1, weekend_2]).OnlyEnforceIf(boolvar)
model.Add(x == i).OnlyEnforceIf(boolvar)
model.Add(x != i).OnlyEnforceIf(boolvar.Not())
```

The out put is:

> Solver exited with nonoptimal status: 1

Do you have any more suggestion?